# Why do I get either NoClassDefFoundError(: org/hibernate/session or org/hibernate/hibernateexception) when trying to instantiate a new TyreH?

Tags: hibernate

I successfully made a TyreCompany application using hibernate and MySql.  The app works fine when ran as Java App from Eclipse but I am consistently hitting a wall when trying to run from the Eclipse-exported JAR (java -jar TyreCompany.jar):  I get either NoClassDefFoundError(: org/hibernate/session) or NoClassDefFoundError (:org/hibernate/hibernateexception) when trying to instantiate  a new TyreH.  What am I missing? SOS !!

Comment: It's missing some hibernate jar in your Classpath, it is due the dependencies (hibernate) not being exported with your jar.

Comment: So I thought! Pretty sure I have references to Hibernate3 jars (lib/required + Hibernate3.jar) both in Eclipse and on my Windows path.  Still a mystery ! Exception thrown has now grown to any of org.hibernate.session, org.hibernate.hibernateException, org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration ..